# How do you say your Youtube account is getting view-suppressed idiomatically?

Tags: idiomatic-language

How do you say your Youtube account is getting view-suppressed idiomatically? I've been trying to find a way to say it and I can't really find a good example on Google, so I thought of asking it here. I thought of a few possibilities, but all of them sounds awkward.

For example:

> YouTube has been responsible of the suppression of views on my YouTube
>   account.
>
> Lately, I believe YouTube is responsible of the view suppression my
>   YouTube videos have been getting.

Not sure if you would agree with me, but they sound odd, so how would you reword them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *suppress* as a verb rather than *suppression* as a noun:

> YouTube has been suppressing my views lately.

If you want to add in the notion of responsibility (as you did in your originals):

> My video views have been suppressed recently, and I believe YouTube is responsible.

Also, it's responsible *for*, not responsible *of*:

> YouTube is responsible for suppressing my views.

Comment: Is there a way to say it with the noun somehow? I've been trying to reword it with "supression" for 3 hours.

Comment: @blackbird - I think that's the root of your problem.

Comment: What about "responsible for the views getting suppressed on my videos"?